# Loop through Files in Folder Using Dir

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to loop through files using `Dir`.  I have written the following, but as expected, the loop is endless as it opens and closes the first file in the folder.

I am wondering if there is a better way than the wildcard method, but can anyone offer me a solution to this.

```
strFolder = "D:\Name\Project\Data\Back-End\Previous\"
strFileSpec = strFolder & "*.xlsx" 
strFileName = Dir(strFileSpec)

Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
    Dim strFilePath As String: strFilePath = strFolder & strFileName
    Set proxy_wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFilePath)
    Set proxySheet = proxy_wbk.Sheets(1)
    siteName = proxySheet.Cells(1, 1).Value

    'do work'

    Workbooks(siteName & "_Jan_2017.xlsx").Close savechanges:=False
Loop
```

Comment: Show more of your code, with the Dir.

Comment: @GordonBell I have updated the post.

Comment: Add `strFileName = Dir`(without parameter) before `Loop` to get the next file name

Comment: Thank you. This worked.  Can you explain why setting `strFileName = Dir` moves it forward. I don't think I quite follow it.  Regardless, I appreciate the help.

Comment: [Scripting.FileSystemObject](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/990/scripting-filesystemobject) on Documentation.SO should have everything you need to know. To avoid downvotes on SO, it's usually a good idea to *research* the topic a little bit before asking.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Glad to see you changed your last comment...

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but my last comment (which was apparently flagged and removed) was exactly what I meant: "vba dir function" turns up [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx) on the first google results page, and it's clearly stated: "You must supply a PathName the first time you call the Dir function. **To retrieve the next item, you can make subsequent calls to the Dir function with no parameters**" - downvote button says "this question does not show any research effort / is not useful", so I downvoted it. Try a bit harder next time.

Comment: Dir calls an underlying Windows function that other apps running at the same time may also call; that can reset the directory and file spec, so your subsequent calls to Dir may return unexpected results. If that's a concern, it's safer to load an array or collection with files that match your spec, then process them afterward by pulling the filenames from the array rather than repeatedly calling Dir.  You could also add another layer of foolproofing by checking each array entry to make sure the path matches the one you expect prior to acting on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

```
files = Dir("/yourpath/*.xlsx")
While files <> ""
    List(i)=files //List(i) will hold the file name 
    files = Dir
Wend
```

Here Dir function returns the file name one by one every time it is called
after all the file names are emptied It returns empty string.

To understand better assume Dir function has static variable in it to hold the filename index in it.

Comment: Please can you add some explanation around the code you've provided? Thank you.

Comment: I have added explanation. Is that clear now?